# Unable to build android app with phonegap/cordova

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, phonegap

I am trying to build an android app with phonegap/cordova but it's failing. Below is the command

```
cordova build android
```

This is the result:

> Android Studio project detected
>   ANDROID_HOME=/home/harish/Android/Sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
>       studio
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
> - Try:
>      Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 0s
>       (node:26252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection       (rejection id: 1): Error: /usr/lib/gradle/4.4.1/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 1
>       (node:26252) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Do you have Android Studio installed? which Gradle version do you have installed?

Comment: @jcesarmobile Yes I have the Android Studio installed and it's running well. The Gradle version is 4.4.1

Comment: I've seen that error when using Java 7, but the log says you have java home set to 8. Maybe it's some incompatibility with openjdk.

Comment: @jcesarmobile so you suggesting to downgrade java to 7

Comment: No, I mean that problem happens when using java 7, not sure why it happens to you if you have java 8 installed. So it might be some openjdk incompatibility.